# Open Windows Explorer and select a file

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to open a Windows Explorer window from a vba form, navigate to a specific file and select it so that the file name is placed in a text box?

Comment: Press the magic key `F1` in VBA Excel and search for `Application.GetOpenFilename` ;)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```
Private Sub openDialog()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select the file."

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        txtFileName = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox

      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

I think this is what you are asking for.