# Activeworkbook changelink

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use activeworkbook.changelink like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink 

Name:= *current workbook*
NewName:= *Open the folder of current workbook from where I can choose the new file*
```

If I have a link in a cell ("c:\Docs\example.xls") but I want to change it to something (I have more files in c:\Docs, like "example2.xls", "example3.xls",...) the macro should open the folder of c:\Docs\ (Browse dialog) from where I could chose the file I want to use.

Can you suggest me something? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you are stuck with and what you are trying to do? If you could give an example of what you would like to happen, showing before and after, that would be helpful.

Comment: Of course. If I have a link in a cell ("c:\Docs\example.xls") but I want to change it to something (I have more files in c:\Docs, like "example2.xls", "example3.xls",...) the macro should open the folder of c:\Docs\ from where I could chose the file I want to use.

Comment: So you want to know how to get a Browse dialog up?

Comment: Yes. Sorry my excel isn't english I didn't know the proper name of it.

Comment: That's ok, I just wanted to be sure what you were having trouble with :). Can you please edit the question to add in this information?

Comment: ok, it's done :)

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10305150/7648526) should help you with the file dialog. You will need to create a `String` variable that stores the file path returned and use `NewName:=myFilePath`. [Documentation about `Application.FileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got time to finish this one. It's working so I share it. Maybe it will be useful for somebody :)

```
Sub Linkchange()

Const RefText = "#REF"
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim txtFileName, Msg As String
Dim OldLink_num As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FindRef As Range
Dim SheetLoop
Dim FirstAddress
Dim UserOption

alink = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources

If IsEmpty(alink) Then

   Msgbox "Nothing is attached."

Else

For Idx = 1 To UBound(alink)
    Msg = Msg & (Idx) & ". " & alink(Idx) & vbCrLf & vbNewLine
Next

Msgbox Msg

   Linkchange_userform.Show 

   'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     'Dim a As Long
     'a = ListBox1.Value
     'Msgbox a & ". is chosen"
     'Unload Me

   'End Sub

   'Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

   'End Sub

   'Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

      'Dim Idx As Long

      'alink = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources

       'For Idx = 1 To UBound(alink)
       '    ListBox1.AddItem Idx
       'Next

    'ListBox1.ListIndex = 0

    'End Sub

OldLink_num = Linkchange_userform.ListBox1.Value

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Title = "Pick a file!"
  .InitialFileName = Left$(alink(OldLink_num), InStrRev(alink(OldLink_num), "\"))
  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

  If .Show = True Then
    txtFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
    Exit Sub
  End If

End With

ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=alink(OldLink_num), NewName:=txtFileName, Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks

Msgbox "Ready!"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For SheetLoop = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

Set FindRef = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetLoop).Cells.Find(RefText, lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not FindRef Is Nothing Then
FirstAddress = FindRef.Address

While Not FindRef Is Nothing

  UserOption = Msgbox("Fail at - " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetLoop).Name & ", cell " & FindRef.Address & vbNewLine & "To continue: OK" & vbNewLine & "To exit: Cancel", vbOKCancel)

  If UserOption = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set FindRef = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetLoop).Cells.FindNext(FindRef)
  If FindRef.Address = FirstAddress Then
    Set FindRef = Nothing
  End If

Wend

End If

Next SheetLoop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If


End Sub
```