# How do I remove specific images

Tags: excel, vba

New to using VBA in Excel but got the following macro to successfully copy an image (located at and contained within cell T4) and replicate it into a range of cells the dimensions of which are specified by the values at cells K15 and K17.  Thus if K15 contains 6 and K17 4, a copy of the image is pasted into the 24 cells in the range T6:Y10.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim length_count As Integer
Dim width_count As Integer
'Get Length and Width sizes
length_count = Range("K15").Value
width_count = Range("K17").Value
MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count
'Copy the image located at cell T4
Worksheets("Drawing").Range("T4").Copy
'Select cell range (starting at T6) as defined length and width values
Worksheets("Drawing").Range(Cells(6, 20), Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + 
length_count - 1)).Select
'Paste image into each cell in defined range
Worksheets("Drawing").Paste
MsgBox "Drawing complete"
End Sub
```

What I'm struggling with is how to select and remove these images so that the worksheet is 'reset' prior to executing the macro again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other images on the sheet besides the original in T4 and the copies you've made?

Comment: Tx for quick response. Yes, many, so I need to remove just those created by the macro.

Comment: And when you "reset" the worksheet, I'm assuming the values in K15 and K17 will already have changed.

Comment: Not necessarily.  What I want to do is add 'Reset' code (perhaps using another CommandButton) that would remove just the pasted images prior to new numbers being placed in K15 and K17 ready to create a new drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to delete those pictures:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim length_count As Integer
Dim width_count As Integer
Dim pic As Variant

'Get Length and Width sizes
length_count = Range("K15").Value
width_count = Range("K17").Value
MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count

For Each pic In Worksheets("Drawing").Shapes
    If Not Intersect(Range(pic.TopLeftCell, pic.BottomRightCell), Worksheets("Drawing").Range(Cells(6, 20), Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1))) Is Nothing Then
        pic.Delete
    End If
Next pic

End Sub
```

---

By the way, your code to copy pictures can be simplified to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim length_count As Integer
Dim width_count As Integer
'Get Length and Width sizes
length_count = Range("K15").Value
width_count = Range("K17").Value
MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count
'Copy the image located at cell T4 and paste it into each cell in defined range
Worksheets("Drawing").Range("T4").Copy Worksheets("Drawing").Range(Cells(6, 20), Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1))
MsgBox "Drawing complete"
End Sub
```

---

Edit: an answer to the comment

```
Sub AddPics()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim length_count As Integer
    Dim width_count As Integer
    Dim pic() As Variant
    Dim picName As String
    Dim index As Long
    Dim xFilename As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")
    picName = "InsertedImage"
    'xFilename = "your pics name"   'By default I made it to open the explorer window to choose the picture
                                    'If you want to made it a permanent choice write there its name without extension
                                    'With this code it's going to choose the file with that name in the same folder
                                    'as is the workbook
                                    'The extension is jpg
                                    'If you have a different, modify the code or change so that you write the name with the extensinon
                                    'It is not a problem if explorer windows is used

    With ws

        'Get Length and Width sizes
        'length_count = .Range("K15").Value
        length_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the lenght number:", "lenght number", Range("K15").Value, , , , , 1)
        'width_count = .Range("K17").Value
        width_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the width number:", "width number", Range("K17").Value, , , , , 1)
        MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count

        ReDim pic(1 To length_count * width_count)

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'Copy the image located at cell T4 and paste it into each cell in defined range

        .Pictures.Insert(openDialog(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path)).Select 'Open the dialog window
        '.Pictures.Insert(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & xFilename & ".jpg").Select
        Selection.Name = picName & 1
        Set pic(1) = .Shapes(picName & 1)


        ' It resizes the pictures to fit the cells, you may remove this part or modify it
        If .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)).Cells(1).Height > .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)).Cells(1).Width Then
            pic(1).Width = .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)).Cells(1).Width
        Else
            pic(1).Height = .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)).Cells(1).Height
        End If
        ''''''

        pic(1).Top = .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)).Cells(1).Top
        pic(1).Left = .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)).Cells(1).Left

        For i = 2 To length_count * width_count
            Set pic(i) = pic(1).Duplicate
            pic(i).Name = picName & i
            pic(i).Top = .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)).Cells(i).Top
            pic(i).Left = .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)).Cells(i).Left
        Next i

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    End With

        MsgBox "Drawing complete"
End Sub


Sub DeletePics()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim length_count As Integer
Dim width_count As Integer
Dim picNumber As Long
Dim picName As String
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")
picName = "InsertedImage"

    With ws

        'Get Length and Width sizes
        'length_count = .Range("K15").Value
        length_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the lenght number:", "lenght number", Range("K15").Value, , , , , 1)
        'width_count = .Range("K17").Value
        width_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the width number:", "width number", Range("K17").Value, , , , , 1)
        MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count

        For i = 1 To length_count * width_count
                .Shapes(picName & i).Delete
        Next i

    End With

End Sub


Sub DeleteAllInsertedPics()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim length_count As Integer
Dim width_count As Integer
Dim picNumber As Long
Dim pic As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")
picName = "InsertedImage"

    With ws

        For Each pic In .Shapes
            If Left(pic.Name, Len(picName)) = picName Then
                pic.Delete
            End If
        Next pic

    End With

End Sub

Private Function openDialog(defaultPath As String)
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select the file."

      ' Default path
      .InitialFileName = defaultPath

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "pictures", "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        openDialog = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox

      End If
   End With
End Function
```

I used and modified the code from there:

[Open Windows Explorer and select a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304989/open-windows-explorer-and-select-a-file)

---

New Edit

```
Sub AddPics()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim length_count As Integer
    Dim width_count As Integer
    Dim pic() As Variant
    Dim picName As String
    Dim index As Long
    Dim xFilename As String
    Dim xRng
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")
    picName = "InsertedImage"

    'xFilename = "your pics name"   'By default I made it to open the explorer window to choose the picture
                                    'If you want to make it a permanent choice write there its name without extension
                                    'With this code it's going to choose the file with that name in the same folder
                                    'as is the workbook
                                    'The extension is jpg
                                    'If you have a different extension, modify the code or change it so that you write the name with the extensinon
                                    'It is not a problem if explorer windows is used
    With ws

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Get Length and Width sizes
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'length_count = .Range("K15").Value
        'length_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the lenght number:", "lenght number", Range("K15").Value, , , , , 1)
        'width_count = .Range("K17").Value
        'width_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the width number:", "width number", Range("K17").Value , , , , ,1)

        'MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count

        'Set xRng = .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)) 'Choose the range po pictures

        'ReDim pic(1 To length_count * width_count) 'Resizes the size of array of pictures to store them all


        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Get Length and Width sizes (optional instead of the previous)
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Select range", "Get Range", , , , , , 8) 'Open Input box for choosing the range
        If xRng Is Nothing Then                 ' That if-statement is added in advance for "On Error Resume Next"  which can be used
            MsgBox "Empty range was chosen"     ' Now empty range terminates the procedure anyway
            Exit Sub
        End If

        length_count = xRng.Columns.Count
        width_count = xRng.Rows.Count

        MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count

        ReDim pic(1 To length_count * width_count) 'Resizes the size of array of pictures to store them all



        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Insert an image
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Set pic(1) = .Pictures.Insert(openDialog(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path))    'It opens the dialog window
                                                                                    'In openDialog() pass the defaulty path
                                                                                    'In my case it is 'Application.ThisWorkbook.Path'

        'Set pic(1) = .Pictures.Insert(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & xFilename & ".jpg")
        pic(1).Name = picName & 1



        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' It resizes the pictures to fit the cells, you may remove this part or modify it
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        If xRng.Cells(1).Height > xRng.Cells(1).Width Then
            pic(1).Width = xRng.Cells(1).Width
            If pic(1).Height > xRng.Cells(1).Height Then
                pic(1).Height = xRng.Cells(1).Height
            End If
        Else
            pic(1).Height = xRng.Cells(1).Height
            If pic(1).Width > xRng.Cells(1).Width Then
                pic(1).Width = xRng.Cells(1).Width
            End If
        End If



        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Position the picture in the first cell (the part after plus sign is to center the picture
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        pic(1).Top = xRng.Cells(1).Top + 0.5 * (xRng.Cells(1).Height - pic(1).Height)
        pic(1).Left = xRng.Cells(1).Left + 0.5 * (xRng.Cells(1).Width - pic(1).Width)



        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Duplicate and position the rest of the pictures in the xRng (the selected range) (the part after plus sign is to center the picture
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        For i = 2 To length_count * width_count
            Set pic(i) = pic(1).Duplicate
            pic(i).Name = picName & i
            pic(i).Top = xRng.Cells(i).Top + 0.5 * (xRng.Cells(i).Height - pic(i).Height)
            pic(i).Left = xRng.Cells(i).Left + 0.5 * (xRng.Cells(i).Width - pic(i).Width)
        Next i

    End With

        MsgBox "Drawing complete"

End Sub


Sub DeletePics()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim length_count As Integer
Dim width_count As Integer
Dim picNumber As Long
Dim picName As String
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")
picName = "InsertedImage"

    With ws

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Get Length and Width sizes
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'length_count = .Range("K15").Value
        'length_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the lenght number:", "lenght number", Range("K15").Value, , , , , 1)
        'width_count = .Range("K17").Value
        'width_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the width number:", "width number", Range("K17").Value , , , , ,1)

        'MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count


        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Get Length and Width sizes (optional instead of the previous)
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Select range", "Get Range", , , , , , 8) 'Open Input box for choosing the range
        If xRng Is Nothing Then                 ' That if-statement is added in advance for "On Error Resume Next"  which can be used
            MsgBox "Empty range was chosen"     ' Now empty range terminates the procedure anyway
            Exit Sub                            ' Unfortunately if the pictures fill the cells almost completely
        End If                                  ' One cannot select the range and has to write it manually in the InputBox

        length_count = xRng.Columns.Count
        width_count = xRng.Rows.Count

        MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Delete pictures in selected cells
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        For i = 1 To length_count * width_count
                .Shapes(picName & i).Delete
        Next i

    End With

End Sub


Sub DeleteAllInsertedPics()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim length_count As Integer
Dim width_count As Integer
Dim picNumber As Long
Dim pic As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")
picName = "InsertedImage"


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Delete all the pictures that start with picName (the best option to delete I guess)
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    With ws

        For Each pic In .Shapes
            If Left(pic.Name, Len(picName)) = picName Then
                pic.Delete
            End If
        Next pic

    End With

End Sub

Private Function openDialog(defaultPath As String)
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select the file."

      ' Default path
      .InitialFileName = defaultPath

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "pictures", "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        openDialog = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox

      End If
   End With
End Function
```

---

An edit to resolve excel 2007 error (look in the comments).

To be honest, I don't really know why that error occured.
I declared pic() array as Shape now instead of Variant. It doesn't generate problems but I couldn't insert a picture an assign it to a Shape object, so instead I created a new Picture object (pic_one) and then assigned it to a Shape object (pic(1))

```
Sub AddPics()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim length_count As Integer
    Dim width_count As Integer
    Dim pic_one As Picture
    Dim pic() As Shape
    Dim picName As String
    Dim index As Long
    Dim xFilename As String
    Dim xRng
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")
    picName = "InsertedImage"

    'xFilename = "your pics name"   'By default I made it to open the explorer window to choose the picture
                                    'If you want to make it a permanent choice write there its name without extension
                                    'With this code it's going to choose the file with that name in the same folder
                                    'as is the workbook
                                    'The extension is jpg
                                    'If you have a different extension, modify the code or change it so that you write the name with the extensinon
                                    'It is not a problem if explorer windows is used
    With ws

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Get Length and Width sizes
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'length_count = .Range("K15").Value
        'length_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the lenght number:", "lenght number", Range("K15").Value, , , , , 1)
        'width_count = .Range("K17").Value
        'width_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the width number:", "width number", Range("K17").Value , , , , ,1)

        'MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count

        'Set xRng = .Range(.Cells(6, 20), .Cells(6 + width_count - 1, 20 + length_count - 1)) 'Choose the range po pictures

        'ReDim pic(1 To length_count * width_count) 'Resizes the size of array of pictures to store them all


        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Get Length and Width sizes (optional instead of the previous)
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Select range", "Get Range", , , , , , 8) 'Open Input box for choosing the range
        If xRng Is Nothing Then                 ' That if-statement is added in advance for "On Error Resume Next"  which can be used
            MsgBox "Empty range was chosen"     ' Now empty range terminates the procedure anyway
            Exit Sub
        End If

        length_count = xRng.Columns.Count
        width_count = xRng.Rows.Count

        MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count

        ReDim pic(1 To length_count * width_count) 'Resizes the size of array of pictures to store them all



        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Insert an image
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Set pic_one = .Pictures.Insert(openDialog(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path))    'It opens the dialog window
                                                                                    'In openDialog() pass the defaulty path
                                                                                    'In my case it is 'Application.ThisWorkbook.Path'

        'Set pic_one = .Pictures.Insert(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & xFilename & ".jpg")
        pic_one.Name = picName & 1



        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' It resizes the pictures to fit the cells, you may remove this part or modify it
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        If xRng.Cells(1).Height > xRng.Cells(1).Width Then
            pic_one.Width = xRng.Cells(1).Width
            If pic_one.Height > xRng.Cells(1).Height Then
                pic_one.Height = xRng.Cells(1).Height
            End If
        Else
            pic_one.Height = xRng.Cells(1).Height
            If pic_one.Width > xRng.Cells(1).Width Then
                pic_one.Width = xRng.Cells(1).Width
            End If
        End If



        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Position the picture in the first cell (the part after plus sign is to center the picture
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        pic_one.Top = xRng.Cells(1).Top + 0.5 * (xRng.Cells(1).Height - pic_one.Height)
        pic_one.Left = xRng.Cells(1).Left + 0.5 * (xRng.Cells(1).Width - pic_one.Width)



        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Duplicate and position the rest of the pictures in the xRng (the selected range) (the part after plus sign is to center the picture
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Set pic(1) = .Shapes(picName & 1)

        For i = 2 To length_count * width_count
            Set pic(i) = pic(1).Duplicate
            pic(i).Name = picName & i
            pic(i).Top = xRng.Cells(i).Top + 0.5 * (xRng.Cells(i).Height - pic(i).Height)
            pic(i).Left = xRng.Cells(i).Left + 0.5 * (xRng.Cells(i).Width - pic(i).Width)
        Next i

    End With

        MsgBox "Drawing complete"

End Sub


Sub DeletePics()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim length_count As Integer
Dim width_count As Integer
Dim picNumber As Long
Dim picName As String
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")
picName = "InsertedImage"

    With ws

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Get Length and Width sizes
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'length_count = .Range("K15").Value
        'length_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the lenght number:", "lenght number", Range("K15").Value, , , , , 1)
        'width_count = .Range("K17").Value
        'width_count = Application.InputBox("Choose the width number:", "width number", Range("K17").Value , , , , ,1)

        'MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count


        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Get Length and Width sizes (optional instead of the previous)
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Select range", "Get Range", , , , , , 8) 'Open Input box for choosing the range
        If xRng Is Nothing Then                 ' That if-statement is added in advance for "On Error Resume Next"  which can be used
            MsgBox "Empty range was chosen"     ' Now empty range terminates the procedure anyway
            Exit Sub                            ' Unfortunately if the pictures fill the cells almost completely
        End If                                  ' One cannot select the range and has to write it manually in the InputBox

        length_count = xRng.Columns.Count
        width_count = xRng.Rows.Count

        MsgBox "Length is " & length_count & ", Width is " & width_count

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Delete pictures in selected cells
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        For i = 1 To length_count * width_count
                .Shapes(picName & i).Delete
        Next i

    End With

End Sub


Sub DeleteAllInsertedPics()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim length_count As Integer
Dim width_count As Integer
Dim picNumber As Long
Dim pic As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")
picName = "InsertedImage"


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Delete all the pictures that start with picName (the best option to delete I guess)
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    With ws

        For Each pic In .Shapes
            If Left(pic.Name, Len(picName)) = picName Then
                pic.Delete
            End If
        Next pic

    End With

End Sub

Private Function openDialog(defaultPath As String)
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select the file."

      ' Default path
      .InitialFileName = defaultPath

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "pictures", "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        openDialog = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox

      End If
   End With
End Function
```

Comment: Strange.  Worked OK 1st time I ran your delete code but now get a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error."

Comment: Well, it would be helpful to know at which line it crashed. It may be some problem with the scope. Where do you store the code? Is it worksheet level or a separate module? You can add `Worksheets("Drawing").` before the Range everywhere or use `With Worksheets("Drawing") ... some code and you use dots instead of that long statement ... End With`. It is easy to find how to use it.

Comment: `Worksheets("Drawing").Range(Cells(6, 20),....)` will error if "Drawing" is not the activesheet, since the `Cells()` will default to the activesheet.  Good practice to qualify *all* range references with a worksheet object.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I have the code working I think I might try having the image stored as a jpeg file in the same (or possibly a subfolder) of where the workbook is located. Any pointers as to how I would change the code to refer to this file rather than Range("T4") would be appreciated.

Comment: I edited my answer, look at it. I haven't encounterd any errors but I checked it just briefly. If I find time, I revise the code.

Comment: Many thanks. I will digest your coding Shelty and try it later!

Comment: All works fine and have learnt a great deal from everyone's answers particularly the example of how to select the picture file from Windows Explorer dialog.

Comment: Update!  All works fine with Excel 2016.  However, when I run on Excel 2007 I get a Type Mismatch on the statement: Set pic(i) = pic(1).Duplicate in the code that replicates the image. Assume this is something to do with Excel 2016 being able to manage some sort of variable conversion which isn't available in Excel 2007.  Any thoughts on how to rectify this (other than updating to Excel 2016)!

Comment: Well, for the time being you can put instead of `Set pic(i) = pic(1).Duplicate` these lines: `pic(1).Copy` ; `.Paste` ; `Set pic(i) = Selection.ShapeRange`. It works rather slow. If you look there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.duplicate it says that this method 'returns a reference to the new copy'. To me it looks like it doesn't in excel 2007 but I haven't found any more information. I may find a nicer solution.

Comment: I edited the answer and added a better code. I wrote there what changes I made. I seems better than that copy and paste what I wrote above.

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't get the Copy/Paste to work but your new code works fine in 2007.